# Click on Table Link

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am completely new to excel vba and i want to do it for a specific requirement how to click on the Unit history button in the website. Could anyone help me with a program?

[image]

I used the following working template code:

```
Sub ClickLink()
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With objIE
        .navigate "https://www.google.com"
        .Visible = 1
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set htmlDoc = .document
        Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("A")

        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
            If htmlInput.innerText = "Gmail" Then
                htmlInput.Focus
                htmlInput.Click
                Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
                Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
                Exit For
            End If
            'Debug.Print "Frame " & x & ": " & htmlInput.innerText
        Next htmlInput

        Set htmlDoc = .document
        Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("A")

        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
            If htmlInput.innerText = "Sign in" Then
                htmlInput.Focus htmlInput.Click
                Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
                Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
                Exit For
            End If
            'Debug.Print "Frame " & x & ": " & htmlInput.innerText
        Next htmlInput
    End With
End Sub
```

Replaced url with my url such that I had:

```
Sub ClickLink()
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With objIE
        .navigate "http://insraa01.asia.delphiauto.net/"
        .Visible = 1
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set htmlDoc = .document
        Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("A")

        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
            If htmlInput.innerText = "Unit History" Then
                htmlInput.Focus
                htmlInput.Click
                Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
                Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
                Exit For
            End If
            'Debug.Print "Frame " & x & ": " & htmlInput.innerText
        Next htmlInput
    End With
End Sub
```

It is not working because my desired element to click is a table row and I don't know how to do this. I have gone through [Clicking Table Row in HTML Table using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233644/clicking-table-row-in-html-table-using-vba) but remain confused as to taking reference to the tables and clicking on Table contents.

The element to click on is highlighted in the image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)
might help you to improve your question.

Comment: If you have done nothing yet, you will find many tutorials about how to do web-scraping with VBA. Do some research, read them carefully and give it a try on your own. If you get stuck or errors come back with a good question related to the code you have tried.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a css class selector in combination with `href` attribute selector and ends with operator to target the `a` tag of interest (the fact it is within a `table` is irrelevant) and it looks like you have a parent frame to negotiate as well.

```
ie.document.querySelector("frame").item(index of frame).contentDocument.querySelector(".nonvis[href$=unithistory]").click
```

This says to click the first element which has `class` `nonvis` and `href` attribute who's value ends with `unithistory`.
You need to determine at which index of frames the frame is that contains your `a` tag e.g. the first frame would be 0, the second would be 1 etc.

Read about css selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors